# How does stackoverflow recognize me?

Tags: web, authentication

I've found a nice web site www.stackoverflow.com and registered in there using my personal e-mail.
All my cookies are purged every time i close my browser(or even purged manually).
And each time i'm visiting main page(no session info stored in querystring), it recognize me as registered user.
How does he do this ?

I'm using Opera 12.17

Answer (score 1):

It could be storing information in `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage. In fact, if you open up the console and enter "localStorage" you will get back a session key